# scaling a database on cloud and on local servers

Tags: mongodb, data-warehouse, sharding

I am considering using mongo db (it could be postgresql or any other ) as a data warehouse, my concern is that up to twenty or more users could be running queries at a time and this could have serious implications in terms of performance. 
My question is what is the best approach to handle this in a cloud based and non cloud based environment? Do cloud based db's automatically handle this? If so would the data be consistent through all instances if a refresh on the data was made? In a non cloud based environment would the best approach be to load balance all instances? Again how would you ensure data integrity for all instances?

thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps read the question?

Comment: perhaps we can be adults and not resort to swearing at people on stack exchange? I don't think being provocative  and rude is very productive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think auto sharding is what I am looking for

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/MongoDB-sharding-guide.pdf